# Redux saga terminate action triggered for unknown reason

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

A terminate action is triggered by redux-saga for unknown reason on the server (SSR) and I can't figure out why.
This is really a blocking issue and I have no idea how to further debug it...

```
app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/reload/reload.js') return next();
    console.log('router hit');
    const store = configureStore();

    let htmlPath = config.get('iso.htmlRoot');

    fs.readFile(htmlPath, "utf8", function(err, template) {

        const context = {};

        console.log('before saga middleware is run');
        store.runSaga(sagas).toPromise().then(() => {
            console.log('saga middleware callback');
            const preloadedState = store.getState();
            const html = renderer(template, req.path, context, store);
            const strPreloadedState = JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c');

            console.log('preloadState', strPreloadedState);
            const htmlWithPreload = html.replace('{preloadedState}', strPreloadedState);

            console.log('*********  wtf  ********');
            res.set('content-type', 'text/html');
            res.send(htmlWithPreload);
            res.end();

        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e.message);
            res.status(500).send(e.message)
        });
        console.log('first renderer');

        renderer(template, req.path, context, store);

        store.close();

    });
});
```

store.close triggers the END event so AFAIK there really shouldn't be issues in between requests.

I have a monitor on my redux-saga middleware, and noticed that there is a terminate event:

```
store initiated
before saga middleware is run
event rootSaga started { effectId: 81, saga: [GeneratorFunction: rootSaga], args: [] }
fetch gists saga start
watch effect id 85
watch effect @@redux-saga/TERMINATE --> why??
```

My saga is very straightforward:

```
import { all, call, put, fork, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

import {
  FETCH_GISTS_REQUESTED,
  FETCH_GISTS__SUCCEEDED,
  FETCH_GISTS__FAILED,
} from './GetTrendingActions';

export const fetchUrl = () => fetch('https://api.github.com/gists', {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
}).then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error();
  }

  return response.json();
});

export function* fetchGists() {
  console.log('test');
  try {
    const gists = yield call(fetchUrl);
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_GISTS__SUCCEEDED,
      payload: {
        gists: gists.map(gist => ({
          id: gist.id,
          title: gist.description || 'pas de titre',
        })),
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_GISTS__FAILED,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
}

export function* fetchGistsSaga() {
  console.log('fetch gists saga start');
  var task = yield takeLatest(FETCH_GISTS_REQUESTED, fetchGists); --> Something going wrong here 
  console.log('saga not finished');
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(fetchGistsSaga)
  ]);
}
```

I have published my codebase on Github here: https://github.com/kimgysen/zwoop-website

You can jus run it using:

```
npm install 
npm run start:iso:dev
```

or when on windows:

```
npm run:start:iso:dev:win
```

When you run the code, the saga will work fine on the first run, but when refreshing the page, the saga watcher callback isn't run as expected as you will see.
Any idea?

The Trending component will trigger a request to get remote gists (which I have added as a test api). I have no clue as of why the saga watcher works fine on initial pageload, but not on subsequent requests.

Sorry if the question isn't all that clear. If you run the example, you will see. 
Thanks for advising.

Edit:
I haven't made a lot of progress after a lot of experimentation and this is starting to become a pain.
When printing the rootSaga that the saga middleware uses to spin up the generators, I get the following output:

```
before saga middleware is run function rootSaga() {
  return _babel_runtime_regenerator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.wrap(function rootSaga$(_context3) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next) {
        case 0:
          _context3.next = 2;
          return Object(redux_saga_effects__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["all"])([Object(redux_saga_effects__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["fork"])(fetchGistsSaga)]);

        case 2:
        case "end":
          return _context3.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _marked3);
}
```

I'm using `"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4"` and in .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import", ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
    "regenerator": true
  }]]
}
```

I strongly wonder if this could have anything to do with the problem, but it's a shot in the dark.
However, I am unable to debug the server code (the webpack compiled code) using Node devTools since the compiled webpack code uses `eval` for all its statements.

I refer once again to my github repo, because this may be too hard to solve otherwise: https://github.com/kimgysen/zwoop-website
I fixed the favicon.ico issue.
Also note you may have to start: `npm run start:iso:dev` a second time because a race condition that I have yet to fix (or alternative build and run manually server and client). But it should work seemslessly otherwise.
Do note that on the client, everything works as expected, so it is really only a problem for the server-rendering.

So the saga works as expected on first render, then all subsequent server renders fail to call the watcher saga. Please advise.

Edit 2:

I didn't look further into this in the end. Redux-saga seemed to work well on the client, but I didn't manage to get it working for SSR.
I already decided to study RxJS and will probably take a look at redux-observable. If anyone still cares to look at this, providing an answer is never lost.